# Имена классов

Tags: php

- В качестве разделителей слов  используйте заглавные буквы, строчные  для остальной части слов;
- Первая буква в имени - заглавная;

**Пример**

> class NameOneTwo
>
> class Name

Имена аргументов в методах

- Первая буква - всегда строчная;
- Все  остальные слова в имени начинаются с большой буквы, как при именовании  классов.

**Пример**

> function HandleError($errorNumber) {
>
> ```
> $error = new OsError;
>
> $time_of_error = $error->GetTimeOfError();
>
> $error_processor = $error->GetErrorProcessor();
> ```
>
> }

Кто согласен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы описали -  всего лишь одно из давным-давно извеcтных соглашений по именованию классов/методов/функций/etc, не более и не менее, рекомендуемое к использованию, например, в C# (и не очень рекомендуемое, например, в Java). Что касается этих ваших php, то для половины похапе-погромистов единственным "тру"-подходом является что-то вроде eto_moya_super_funkzia()

Кстати говоря, вот этим вот идентификатором: $time_of_error вы сами противоречите описываемому вами подходу. В этом случае его логичнее назвать $errorTime - нижние подчеркивания и предлоги вроде of только занимают место и не вписываются в общую картину.
А вообще на эту тему полистайте вот [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38553/) (главным образом комменты)